# How to extract the strong data from div tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Python to scrape the data. Can someone help me in how to extract strong data from div using python:

```
<div class="type"><span class="tag_ts" title="Time sale">Time sale</span></div><del>$35.90</del><strong title="Discounted Price">$12.90</strong>
```

here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen
myurl=Request('https://www.qoo10.sg/gmkt.inc/search/CategoryImageSearch.aspx?choice_no=569', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
pagehtml=urlopen(myurl).read()
pagesoup=soup(pagehtml,'html.parser')
containers=pagesoup.find_all('div',{'class':'item_wrap'})
container=containers[0]

for container in containers:
   prdt_price=container.find_all('div',{'class':'prc'})
   price=prdt_price[0].text
   print(price)
```

my output is:Time sale$35.90$12.90

i need to get $12.90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text out of strong element,(if you are sure that all elements in containers has a strong element), you can use `container.strong.text`

To get only the strong text, use something like:

```
for container in containers:
    prdt_price=container.find_all('div',{'class':'prc'})
    price=prdt_price[0].strong.text
    print(price)
```

Alternatively, you can reduce it to:

```
for container in containers:
    print(container.find_all('div',{'class':'prc'})[0].strong.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change

```
prdt_price=container.find_all('div',{'class':'prc'})
```

to

```
prdt_price = container.find_all('strong')
```